# AutoHotkey - Zip called as a part of a path

Tags: path, zip, autohotkey, shortcut

**1.** I am in a certain folder called "2" where are different kind of files and the path looks like this:

> "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Named_Folder\1\2"

I want to put all those files in there in a Zip and how should the script look like so at the end the Zip would be called "Named_Folder", the same as the folder in the path ? Need to mention that the "Named_Folder" will have different name each time. So how to name the zip as two directories above.

**2.** Till now I have just found the script to put all those files in a zip:

```
    #IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass 
    Send ^a                 ; Select All
    Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
    Sleep 100
    Send n              ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "Enter" key
    return
```

And how the script should look like to combine the **1.** and the **2.** step ? With one letter shortcut.

So at the end the result should look like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwgCE.jpg)

**3.** And then I would like to combine below two scripts (F2 F3 or even F1 if it changes anything) with one letter shortcut (4 first lines are from default AHK file):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


#If WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") ; explorer

F1::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
; IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\
    Run, %Fullpath%\2
return

F2::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
; IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\
    Run, %Fullpath%\1\2
return

#If


#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

F3::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := % window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
if (SubStr(Fullpath, -3) = "\1\2")
{
StringReplace, Fullpath, Fullpath, :,
StringTrimRight, Fullpath, Fullpath, 4
StringSplit, folder_array, Fullpath, \,
MsgBox, % folder_array%folder_array0%
    Send ^a                 ; Select All
    Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
    Sleep 100
    Send n              ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the     "Enter" key
        Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
        SendInput, % folder_array%folder_array0%
}
return

#IfWinActive
```

**4.** And then extract the zip (right click-->context menu-->Extract to "folder with the same name as zip"

[Context menu entry example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ficc7.jpg)

So it creates a folder named "NAMED_FOLDER" with all the extracted content.
I know that when I select the zip and press mouse right-button (to open context menu) and press letter "e" it works.

**5.** Then move this Zip and This new Extracted Folder to Desktop in a Folder "FINAL"

And at the end to do all those 5 steps with one letter shortcut. That would do some voodoo magic for me which I really need for the workflow.

Comment: There is no need to inconvenience yourself with the user interface, use the command line instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you asking. Are you having some problem with the code you shown?

Comment: Nop, the code in the 2. step works just fine. I'm asking that all those files in the folder "2" gets zipped with the same name (automatically) as two folders up - "Named_Folder". Cause it's time consuming and painful to do it 100 times sometimes by copy-paste "Named_Folder" to this newly created ZIP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

F4::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
IfNotExist, %Fullpath%\1\2
{
MsgBox, The folder "%Fullpath%\1\2" doesn't exist
    return
}
Run, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWait, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinActivate, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWaitActive,%Fullpath%\1\2
StringReplace, Fullpath2, Fullpath, :,
StringSplit, folder_array, Fullpath2, \,
FolderName = % folder_array%folder_array0%
; MsgBox, % folder_array%folder_array0%
FileCopyDir  %Fullpath%\1\2, %A_Desktop%\FINAL\%FolderName%
; Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
    Send ^a                 ; Select All
    Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
    Sleep 100
    Send n              ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the     "Enter" key
        Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
        SendInput, % folder_array%folder_array0%
        Send {Enter}
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, 500
return

#IfWinActive

Move_ZIP:
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip
{
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, off
FileMove, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip, %A_Desktop%\FINAL
}
return
```

or this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass

F4::
for window in ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").Windows
try Fullpath := window.Document.Folder.Self.Path
IfNotExist, %Fullpath%\1\2
{
MsgBox, The folder "%Fullpath%\1\2" doesn't exist
    return
}
Run, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWait, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinActivate, %Fullpath%\1\2
WinWaitActive,%Fullpath%\1\2
StringReplace, Fullpath2, Fullpath, :,
StringSplit, folder_array, Fullpath2, \,
FolderName = % folder_array%folder_array0%
; MsgBox, % folder_array%folder_array0%
; Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
    Send ^a                 ; Select All
    Send, {AppsKey}         ; Press the "context menu" key
    Sleep 100
    Send n              ; Select "Send to" with the "n" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Right}            ; Open "Sent to" with the "right arrow" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Down}             ; Select "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the "arrow down" key
    Sleep 100
    Send {Enter}            ; Execute "Compressed (zipped) folder" with the     "Enter" key
        Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
        SendInput, % folder_array%folder_array0%
        Send {Enter}
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, 500
return

#IfWinActive

Move_ZIP:
FileCreateDir %A_Desktop%\FINAL
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip
{
SetTimer, Move_ZIP, off
FileMove, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip, %A_Desktop%\FINAL
Sleep 2000      ; wait 2 seconds
SetTimer, CopyDir, 500
}
return

CopyDir:
IfExist, %Fullpath%\1\2\%FolderName%.zip
    return
SetTimer, CopyDir, off
FileCopyDir  %Fullpath%\1\2, %A_Desktop%\FINAL\%FolderName%
return
```

Comment: This one works almost perfect! The only imperfection is in the step 4. But I  improved my post for step 4 to be more specific. But actually when I see how your script works, this ZIP could be also extracted in the "FINAL" folder.

Comment: You don`t need to extract the ZIP if you use FileCopyDir before creating the ZIP.  I edited the above code accordingly.

Comment: Ok, that's another way but it works fine. Hmm, now there is another problem: In the "FINAL" folder and when I open the ZIP and the Folder, in both of them there is an Extra zip, which shoud't be there [link]http://screencast.com/t/mpIRdVU7

Comment: It seems as though your system is perhaps somewhat slower or sometimes overloaded. Try the second code instead.

Comment: Ok, just one last question about the script, how to implement that it opens in the same window ? like this script from your other topic [link]https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/102127-navigating-explorer-directories/#entry634365  Ok, your above answer.

Comment: Replace "Run, %Fullpath%\1\2" with "NavRun( Fullpath "\1\2")" and add the functions "GetActiveExplorer()" and "NavRun(Path)" to your script.

Comment: Yes, it worked ! Overall question: There are two places with time 2 sec. If I would put there "Sleep 100" there is a big chance that my system will get overloaded ? I suppose I need to test it...